# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - Google Dataflow Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running a Google Dataflow job with 150 workers. I am reading the input from Google PubSub. After few enrichment, I am writing the result to Google BigQuery.

For few records I see the below error in Google Dataflow

```
  (787b51f314078308): Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
...
...
...
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
Stack trace truncated. Please see Cloud Logging for the entire trace.
```

I am using 150 workers to process ~75K messages per second. And each message is of size ~1.5KB. Should I further increase the no.of workers? Or should I increase the memory of each workers? How can I increase the memory of each workers?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow may hit issues like these because the memory load on your workers is very high, and it's causing trouble with worker stability. You can try to increase the memory available to workers.

For instance, you may try `n1-highmem-2`.

To chose a machine type, you can use the `--worker_machine_type` parameter in Python, and `--workerMachineType` in Java.

For more information on machine types, check [GCE Machine Types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types)